# Jquery input value does not change if value in depending input changes not manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example placed here http://jsfiddle.net/aS87B/3/

Here are 3 input fields

```
First input<br>
<td class='exchange_rate1'>
<input type="text" name="exchange_rate1" id='exchange_rate1' class='exchange_rate_changed1' value="">
</td>
<br>
Second input<br>
<td>
<input type="text" name="is_exchange_rate_changed1" id="is_exchange_rate_changed1" class='exchange_rate_changed_test1'>
</td>
<br>        
Third input <br>
<td>
<input type="text" name="is_exchange_rate_changed_test1" id="is_exchange_rate_changed_test1">
</td>
```

And here is `jquery`/`javascript`

```
$(".exchange_rate_changed1").on("change", function () {
document.getElementById('is_exchange_rate_changed1').value = 1;
});


$(".exchange_rate_changed_test1").on("change", function () {
document.getElementById('is_exchange_rate_changed_test1').value = 1;
});
```

If type something in First input, value in the Second input changes (it is ok). Expect the same for Third input (if value in the Second input changes, then value in the Third input is one). However it does not work.

What need to change? Suppose instead of `on("change"` need to use something else

**Very bad conclusion** After doing experiments came to conclusion. If value in some input field is set by script (not manually), then I can not base on that value in `javascript`/`jquery` `if` statement.

For example, value in `id="is_exchange_rate_changed_test1"` (Third input) is set/created by script.

Then I want `if ($("#is_exchange_rate_changed_test1").val() > 0)` do something. This does not work because value for the `if` always will be empty.

Please, advice if there is any simple solution. At the moment found only solution to pass the input field value with `ajax` to `php` and in `php` execute `if`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when values are changed by script, events like `change` are not fired, you need to fire them manually. You can trigger the events manually using the .trigger() method provided by jQuery or by using its short hand version as shown below

```
$(".exchange_rate_changed1").on("change", function () {
    $('#is_exchange_rate_changed1').val(1).change()
});


$(".exchange_rate_changed_test1").on("change", function () {
    $('#is_exchange_rate_changed_test1').val(1).trigger('change')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kD3ec/)

Comment: All works, but wrote my conclusion in question after words `Very bad conclusion`. I mean if value latter want to use in `jquery if` statement. Then `if` does not work because for `if` value would not be changed. For my eyes value changed, but for code not...